# c# excel zoom in and out button

Tags: c#, excel, vba, visual-studio-2008, vsto

hi i have a c# program which creates a ribbon on excel-2007, on that ribbon i have two buttons one for zoom in and other for zoom out.

my question is how is it possible so that when i press one of the above buttons and then select the cell or range on a sheet that cell or range will be zoomed in or out?

my problem is i do not know how to assign event for those two buttons?

```
    private void ws_selCh1(Excel.Range Target)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Zoom Out:" +
            Target.get_Address(mis, mis,
            Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, mis, mis)
            );
    }
    private void ws_selCh2(Excel.Range Target)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Zoom In:" +
            Target.get_Address(mis, mis,
            Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, mis, mis)
            );
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();

        ws.SelectionChange +=
            new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
                ws_selCh1
                );

    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();

        ws.SelectionChange +=
            new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
                ws_selCh2
                );

    }
```

currently i was trying to sense the range or cell being selected (but it creates me problem): when i click the second button it displays both messages in ws_selCh1 and ws_selCh2 which i don't want... then, of course, after handling this issue i wanted to add the following ...

```
    ws.Application.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 23;
```

which would increase and decrease it... whenever the appropriate button is clicked and cell +range is selected.

am i on the right way? if no, can you suggest me a better way? also how is it possible that the selected range will be active visible range for the user?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

was answered by Rolf Jaeger at 
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10109322/thanks-rolf.aspx
answer accepted!